# LINQ: Skip and Take duplicates

Tags: c#, linq, duplicates, skip, take

I have an `IQueryable` containing items where everything is already grouped, so something like

```
var animals = new List<string>{"duck", "duck", "duck", "goose", "goose", "cow", "cow", "cow", "rabbit"}.AsQueryable();
```

If I do

```
animals.Skip(2).Take(2);
```

I would get `"duck", "goose"`. However, I would like to skip the first two groups of distinct entries and get the third and fourth (`"cow", "cow", "cow", "rabbit"`). Is there a nice way of doing this in LINQ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use grouping to easily skip the first ones, but it's a bit trickier to get the enumerated set out. I think this should do it:

```
animals.GroupBy(a => a)
       .Skip(2)
       .Take(2)
       .SelectMany(a => a);
```

The `GroupBy` and `Skip` let us handle these as groups, which gets the first bit of your requirement. Then we just re-expand the grouping with the `SelectMany` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

> var animals = new List { "duck", "duck", "duck", "goose",
>   "goose", "cow", "cow", "cow", "rabbit" }.AsQueryable();
>
> var names = animals.Distinct().Skip(2).Take(2).ToList();
>
> var result = animals.Where(name => names.Contains(name));